# Is it possible to run aws s3 sync with boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

AWS CLI provides [aws s3 sync](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command to sync data between 2 locations.

Is there an equivalent command in [boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/sdk-for-python/)?

I can't find this kind of command in [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html).

Comment: No, there is not. You have to implement it yourself or just find online one of many recipes to do it.

Comment: As mentioned, there is no boto3 version of sync.  To recreate it without aws cli requires a bit of work, like [this example](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/1f9ee126203fc8a3435ce52d5a310295), though to do it properly requires use of the TrasnferManager from s3transfer, which requires more work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boto3` does not include s3 sync capabilities. That is only available via the [AWS CLI tool](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).

Interestingly, there's still an open issue at [boto's Github](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3343) that dates back to... 2015.

I guess your best bet is to run the `aws s3 sync` from within a Python script.

Here's a [sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69317895/6106791).

Alternatively, you might want to explore the [DataSync client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/datasync.html).

Answer (score -1):

to add to the above, if you call the process from within a python script and don't have global aws credentials set and don't want to do "aws configure" for whatever reason, if you do this it should work.

```
import os
import subprocess
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = access_key
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = secret_key   
command = "sync local_folder s3://s3_folder"
aws_cli_command = f"aws {command} "
result = subprocess.run(aws_cli_command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```